# Proper way to parse a Json into a list of Object in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

After a Webservice call I get json data like this:

```
{myteam: [
{'id': '1', name: 'xy'},
{'id': '2', name: 'zx'},
{'id': '3', name: 'gh'}
]}
```

I have an class in Flutter:

```
class CardData {
int id;
String name;
CardData({this.id, this.name});
}
```

I parse the data into a CardData list the following way:

```
List<CardData> CardsList = [];

List cards = List();
```

I get the data:

```
Map<String, dynamic> map = await ws.getData();
```

Put into the list

```
cards = map['myteam'];
```

Then iterate the cards:

```
cards.forEach((f) {
CardsList.add(CardData(id: f['id'], name: f['name']));
}
```

I know, that this is not the best way, but working. Now please help me somebody, how can I make the proper solution for this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a logic like this to parse your Json:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String jsonList = '{"myteam":[{"id":"1","name":"xy"},{"id": "2","name":"zx"},{"id":"3","name": "gh"}]}';

  Future<List<CardData>> listOfItems() async {
    var parse = json.decode(jsonList);
    var data = parse['myteam'] as List;
    var map = data.map<CardData>((json) => CardData.parseJson(json));
    return map.toList();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Center(
          child: FutureBuilder<List<CardData>>(
            future: listOfItems(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                return Text(snapshot.data[0].name);
              } else {
                return Text("Loading...");
              }
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CardData {
  String id;
  String name;

  CardData({this.id, this.name});

  factory CardData.parseJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return CardData(id: json['id'], name: json['name']);
  }
}
```

Right now, your Json is using String for the ID (you should remove the quotes to make it an Integer). Also, you `myteam` Json array key doesn't have any quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Your parse looks pretty good, just a minor changes that i can point out are maybe that the constructor of CardData doesn't need the optional parameters and you can have a named constructor to build Cards from json as https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour encourage :

```
CardData.fromJson(Map<String, String> json)
    : id = json['id'],
      name = json['name'];
```

Then use it when you get the data from the server :

```
cards.forEach((f) {
CardsList.add(CardData.fromJson(f));
}
```

The other thing is that if the entire response means something to your domain (the team section composed by card array) you should consider make a class to parse the entire data and avoid use :

```
cards = map['myteam'];
```